Why does clang show zero coverage for C++?
I am doing some fuzz testing using LLVM libFuzzer and Clang, but the coverage I am getting shows 0 hits for the whole file.
To simplify, I went back to the classic libFuzzer example (almost):
extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size)
{
    if (size > 0 && data[0] == 'H')
    {
        if (size > 1 && data[1] == 'I')
        {
            if (size > 2 && data[2] == '!')
            {
                int *foo = (int *)44;
                *foo = 5;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

I compile it using
clang -g -O1 -fsanitize=fuzzer -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping FuzzingApp.cpp -o FuzzingApp.exe
I run it: FuzzingApp.exe . It crashes as expected, and generates a default.profraw as expected.
I convert this to human-readable form:
llvm-profdata merge -sparse *.profraw -o default.profdata
llvm-cov show FuzzingApp.exe -instr-profile=default.profdata

The profile shows me 0 lines covered:
    1|       |// FuzzingApp.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
    2|       |//
    3|       |
    4|       |#include <iostream>
    5|       |
    6|       |/**
    7|       | * @brief Fuzztest entry point.
    8|       | *
    9|       | * The LLVM fuzztest library will call this with random data and sizes, which
   10|       | * need to be interpreted as inputs to the ROM.
   11|       | *
   12|       | * @param   data        random data buffer of length size
   13|       | * @param   size        number of bytes of random data
   14|       | *
   15|       | * @return must be 0
   16|       | */
   17|       |extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size)
   18|      0|{
   19|      0|    if (size > 0 && data[0] == 'H')
   20|      0|    {
   21|      0|        if (size > 1 && data[1] == 'I')
   22|      0|        {
   23|      0|            if (size > 2 && data[2] == '!')
   24|      0|            {
   25|      0|                int *foo = (int *)44;
   26|      0|                *foo = 5;
   27|      0|            }
   28|      0|        }
   29|      0|    }
   30|      0|    return 0;
   31|      0|}

Since it crashed, it must have hit those lines. Why is it showing me it didn't?
Here's the version of clang I'm running (distributed with Visual Studio):
>clang --version
clang version 17.0.3
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin

I have also tried it with the latest build of LLVM+Clang:
clang --version
clang version 18.1.8
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\clang\clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin


What if there is no crash (UB removed)? In such case is coverage properly shown? Anyway who cares about coverage when application crashed, error was detected and should be fixed. Coverge let you estimate level of trust to tests when tests are passing.

The point of fuzz testing is to explore the code paths for unanticipated errors, so it is useful to know how much of the code it has explored. Examples online (see https://github.com/google/fuzzing/blob/master/tutorial/libFuzzerTutorial.md for example) show it listing the hits. It worked fine 18 months ago with clang version 13.0.0. But the build was embedded in some quite gnarly meson files, so I'm willing to believe I've missed some magic parameter, or that the parameters required have changed.

Coverage data is probably generated from a default process exit handler, which isn't called when the app crashes. I use GCC, and it also doesn't generate coverage statistics when the app crashes. @MarekR: coverage data for a crashing app could often be quite useful in some scenarios, actually, because it would show how far the app got.

I also tried using __builtin_trap(); as shown in the libFuzzer example (see https://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html) which again used to work, and now doesn't.

@IanBrockbank I know what is point of fuzz test is. Read my comment again. When test failed, great you have something to fix - at that point coverage is not important since you already have a bug found and bug may make some code unreachable. When test passes then coverage makes sense, since it gives you some measurement, how much you can trust this test. That is why I've started form question: "What if there is no crash (UB removed)?".

@MarekR Ah, apologies. I remembered generating coverage on a previous project, as part of the fuzz testing. Of course, that coverage was for the successful runs to completion, not the unsuccessful runs. You are correct, coverage is generated if it doesn't crash.

As @MarekR alludes, there is no coverage output because the test crashes. If I run the same with few enough iterations that libFuzzer doesn't find the crash, coverage is generated.
> FuzzingApp -runs=10000
INFO: Running with entropic power schedule (0xFF, 100).
INFO: Seed: 990453947
INFO: Loaded 1 modules   (8 inline 8-bit counters): 8 [00007FF7A7DB2008, 00007FF7A7DB2010),
INFO: Loaded 1 PC tables (8 PCs): 8 [00007FF7A7D816E8,00007FF7A7D81768),
INFO: -max_len is not provided; libFuzzer will not generate inputs larger than 4096 bytes
INFO: A corpus is not provided, starting from an empty corpus
#2      INITED cov: 2 ft: 2 corp: 1/1b exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb
#37     NEW    cov: 3 ft: 3 corp: 2/4b lim: 4 exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb L: 3/3 MS: 5 CrossOver-ChangeByte-ChangeByte-ShuffleBytes-InsertByte-
#93     REDUCE cov: 3 ft: 3 corp: 2/3b lim: 4 exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb L: 2/2 MS: 1 EraseBytes-
#103    REDUCE cov: 4 ft: 4 corp: 3/4b lim: 4 exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb L: 1/2 MS: 5 CrossOver-CopyPart-EraseBytes-CrossOver-EraseBytes-
#3365   REDUCE cov: 5 ft: 5 corp: 4/6b lim: 33 exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb L: 2/2 MS: 2 ChangeByte-ChangeBit-
#3436   NEW    cov: 6 ft: 6 corp: 5/9b lim: 33 exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb L: 3/3 MS: 1 CrossOver-
#10000  DONE   cov: 6 ft: 6 corp: 5/9b lim: 98 exec/s: 0 rss: 27Mb
Done 10000 runs in 0 second(s)

> llvm-profdata merge -sparse *.profraw -o default.profdata
> llvm-cov show FuzzingApp.exe -instr-profile=default.profdata
    1|       |// FuzzingApp.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
    2|       |//
    3|       |
    4|       |#include <iostream>
    5|       |
    6|       |/**
    7|       | * @brief Fuzztest entry point.
    8|       | *
    9|       | * The LLVM fuzztest library will call this with random data and sizes, which
   10|       | * need to be interpreted as inputs to the ROM.
   11|       | *
   12|       | * @param   data        random data buffer of length size
   13|       | * @param   size        number of bytes of random data
   14|       | *
   15|       | * @return must be 0
   16|       | */
   17|       |extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size)
   18|  10.0k|{
   19|  10.0k|    if (size > 0 && data[0] == 'H')
   20|  3.29k|    {
   21|  3.29k|        if (size > 1 && data[1] == 'I')
   22|    547|        {
   23|    547|            if (size > 2 && data[2] == '!')
   24|      0|            {
   25|      0|                int *foo = (int *)0;
   26|      0|                *foo = 5;
   27|      0|            }
   28|    547|        }
   29|  3.29k|    }
   30|  10.0k|    return 0;
   31|  10.0k|}

Thank you @MarekR
